# Knowledge translations sent for publication

Tags: apex, knowledge

I'm searching a way to check via apex if a translations has been sent for publication. I'm not figuring out in which object this information is stored.

Any one has any idea how to check if a translation has been sent for publication?

**Edited**

I'm adding some context, so to explain my use-case. 
When you work on a knowledge article, that has not been published, you may sent for publication the translations before that the masterversion is published. If you send an translation for publication, and the master version is not published the translation assume the status "Sent for Publication", but this doesn't correspond to a change in the fields of the KnowledgeArticleVersion. 
When the Master Article is publishe, in the same event, are published also the translation "sent for publication".

I want to know if the traslation has been sent for publication, and still is not published.

**Edited 2**

I'm adding an image to give a more clear idea of what info i want to get from the salesforce database. 
[image]

Comment: I decided to open a ticket to salesforce, I will let you know the next-days as i have more informations from support.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Knowledge Base handy to verify it but have a look at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm. All the way on the bottom it seems that `TranslationCompletedDate` might do the trick, on either generic `KnowledgeArticleVersion` or custom `FAQ__kav`. Maybe you'll have to couple it with article status? `TranslationCompletedDate != null AND PublishStatus = 'Online'`?

Object reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_knowledgearticleversion.htm

Comment: @eyescram thanks, for your feedback, but i'm searching how to check if a translation has been sent for publication, but still is not published. In didn't found a hint, how to check this. unfortunately the PublishStatus is not helping, because in that phase the PublishStatus remains "Draft".

Comment: And none of the date fields is any good? `KnowledgeArticleVersion.TranslationExportedDate` etc? Any chance the act of submitting for translation would be tracked in `knowledgearticleversionhistory`?

Comment: Is all afternoon that i'm trying to figure out this, the fields on knowledgeArticleVersion are not helpful (unfortunately). I tried to query most of the "hidden" objects. (ProcessesInstance, ProcessInstanceWorkitem, and similar objects connected to Salesforce Knowledge). But I was not able to find out where this information is stored.

Comment: One more idea - any chance submitting for translation creates a new KAV record in the target language in status draft?

Comment: it does indeed.

Comment: @eyescream The new version is created if you un-publish an published article, is not created a new one when you send it for publication. The status "Sent for publication" is like a queue where the translation is put, waiting that the MasterVersion (where MasterVersion means, the original article from which the translations are generated).

Comment: Sorry man, out of ideas now. I'll experiment a bit later and if nothing comes up will delete the answer.

Comment: @eyescream No, on the contrary! Thanks for your time, and your thoughts/idea. I hope the support will give us a spot-light on this context.